# Increment a 6 digits number with leading zero and store it in a file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a **powershell** app that is using an incremental number to create directory in a NAS.
The objective is to put **"000001"** before the name of the directory.
I'd like to **increment** this number by putting it in a file and re-using it.
I can only increment without leading 0 so I'm asking for help.
This is what I have now.

Getting the content of the txt

Clear the content

Transform it into int

Increment

Add the content.

Transform it into string

```
        $nb = Get-Content "C:\Users\test\nb.txt"
        Write-Host $nb
        clear-content "C:\Users\test\nb.txt"
        $nb = $nb -as [int]
        $nb = $nb + 1
        ADD-content -path "C:\Users\test\nb.txt" -value $nb
        Write-Host $nb
        $nb = $nb -as [string]
```

Comment: `(1 + (Get-Content .\nb.txt)).ToString('D6') |Set-Content .\nb.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `$nb` from the file, you can create the string with leading zeroes using the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f):

`'{0:000000}' -f (([int]$nb)++)`

So, if `$nb` was 10 when read in, the output would be:

`PS >000011`

Of course, you can capture it in `$nb` again if you need to:

`[string]$nb = '{0:000000}' -f (([int]$nb)++)`

> **Note**: `$nb` is an `int`, so you will need to cast it to keep the leading zeros, or PowerShell will convert the string `000011` back to `11` (an `int`) again.